# How to create an array in sympy with dimension based on a variable?

Tags: python, sympy

I've got two variables: dim and terms. I'd like to use these variables to define an array. For example,

If dim=2 and terms=4, I'd like `m=MutableDenseNDimArray(zeros(terms**dim),(4,4))`

If dim=3 and terms=4, I'd like `m=MutableDenseNDimArray(zeros(terms**dim),(4,4,4))`

If dim=3 and terms=3, I'd like `m=MutableDenseNDimArray(zeros(terms**dim),(3,3,3))`

I've learned that with numpy I could use `np.zeros((terms,) * dim)` but this formatting doesn't work for me with sympy. Can you help?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming the `zeros` function that you tried is `sympy.zeros`? From the docstring:

```
>>> print sympy.zeros.__doc__
Returns a matrix of zeros with ``rows`` rows and ``cols`` columns;
    if ``cols`` is omitted a square matrix will be returned.

    See Also
    ========

    ones
    eye
    diag
```

`sympy.zeros` only supports two integers as arguments, specifying the number of rows and columns of a (2D) `matrix`, not an `NDimArray`; it does not support the same arguments as `numpy.zeros`, which accepts an iterable of integers specifying the dimension of the axes and returns an `array` of any dimension you like.

If you want a `MutableDenseNDimArray` pass in a zeros-like structure already assembled elsewhere, e.g. in `numpy`.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import sympy
>>>
>>> m = sympy.MutableDenseNDimArray(np.zeros((4,)*3))
>>> print m
[[[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]], [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]], [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]], [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]]
```

Or better yet, define your own function to construct the array to save an import:

```
>>> def nested_tuple(size, ndims, t=0):
...     for i in range(ndims):
...         t = (t,)*size
...     
...     return t
...
>>> m = sympy.MutableDenseNDimArray(nested_tuple(4,3))
>>> print m
[[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]]
```